# Regular expression for bb quote (for name and link path) to be included in name?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to make a link to the path in my bb code where the name is. Here is the code I have

Model:

```
$this->attributes['body'] = preg_replace('/\[quote\=(.*?)  path=(\[^ \]*)]/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $body);
```

Here is the HTML being preg_matched:

```
[quote=Verla Schmitt path=/forums/delectus/minima-qui-saepe-consequuntur-vero-architecto-non?page=1#reply-430]Quo praesentium consequuntur omnis placeat odit quia. Quasi rerum quos quasi iure ea. Quae omnis qui dolores sit aspernatur.[/quote]
```

Here is the current output :(
[image]

I'd like it so "Baylee Ritche MD" has the link as noted in path. I've tried to match the regex but my understanding on it is not that great.

Can anyone please help me achieve this feature. Thank you!

**Edit:** I got it to display this with the link to the comment can anyone please help me show the quotes.
[image]

What I want it to show is [quote="Name as link" path="using this path"] Test [/quote]

Comment: I got it to display the link! But however it is now not encapsulated in the bb quote any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression needed a little tweaking.

- `\s` is usually used to represent whitespaces.
- `+` indicates that the previous character should appear at least once
- The second capturing group was very different from the structure of the text. I simplified it as `.*?` as you did with the first capturing group.
- `\` is used before a character to scape it, which means to use it as character, not as an expression modifier.
- `.` is used to represent any character
- `*` indicates that the previous character should appear 0 or more times
- `()` surround capturing groups. We can use those groups for replacing content. They start in order with $1, $2 and so on.

You can try this modified expression `/\[quote\=(.*?)\s+path\=(.*?)\](.*\[\/quote\])/` as in the example below.

```php
$body = "[quote=Verla Schmitt path=/forums/delectus/minima-qui-saepe-consequuntur-vero-architecto-non?page=1#reply-430]Quo praesentium consequuntur omnis placeat odit quia. Quasi rerum quos quasi iure ea. Quae omnis qui dolores sit aspernatur.[/quote]";

$text = preg_replace('/\[quote\=(.*?)\s+path\=(.*?)\](.*\[\/quote\])/', '[quote=<a href="$2">$1</a> path=$2] $3', $body);

echo $text;
// [quote=<a href="/forums/delectus/minima-qui-saepe-consequuntur-vero-architecto-non?page=1#reply-430">Verla Schmitt</a> path=/forums/delectus/minima-qui-saepe-consequuntur-vero-architecto-non?page=1#reply-430] Quo praesentium consequuntur omnis placeat odit quia. Quasi rerum quos quasi iure ea. Quae omnis qui dolores sit aspernatur.[/quote]
```

You can use a tool such as https://regexr.com/5i6n0 to learn about regular expressions and http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4f97a20abf1fb93766119a358eed54144151291 to test your PHP code.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I was trying to use regexr to try to find the solution, however my issue now is that the initial [quote] is gone and it doesn't parse into the block anymore.

Comment: I've updated the expression to account for remaining closing tag if that's what you referred to.

Comment: I actually want it to act as a quote, so it should look like this [quote]( beginning )[/quote](end). I just want to make it so the link INSIDE of the beginning quote block turns into a link to the path, thank you for helping though, I really appreciate it and it would be perfect if I was trying to get rid of the quotes but I'm not. The beginning quote is missing now and I want it back into the code.

Comment: I think you need to improve your question. It is better for us to help you if you show:
1. What the input is.
2. What the problem is.
3. What the output should look like.
If you fail to provide thorough information it's difficult to help.

Comment: So in my edit, it shows the end block quote but not the beginning, I want it to show the beginning as well. I've updated my question a little bit. Hopefully everyone can understand it better now :)

Comment: You are a god. Thank you so much, I really appreciate you.

Comment: Happy to help. Just, please, keep in mind that it's important to make a good description of the problem and the expectations of the solution. Have a happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225759/discussion-between-cristian-llanos-and-user123).